# Is asking for an explanation of some code on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

I just got a code solution from someone, *but* without an explanation, and he already did so much so I didn't ask him for an explanation.

Is asking a new question like "Can anyone tell me how this following code works, what it does?"  or "Can anyone explain this code to me?" on-topic?

Comment: This sounds like a "gimme me the codez" question. Could you post a link to the question in well, question?

Comment: *If* you are going to post such a question, make sure it is laser focused on what you don't understand. Any single line of code can be deconstructed and explained and a few dozen ways; unless you're extremely clear about what you *do* understand and what you *don't* this will likely be received as "too broad" and unclear. Realistically there's probably only one or two things you don't get, spell those out as clearly as possible. In fact, you may figure it out yourself while trying to spell it out...

Comment: Folks, note that the OP said "_And he already did so much so I didn't ask him for an explanation._" - he already feels like he's imposing, but just needs more help understanding (what I think is) an answer someone wrote for him.

Comment: I think for most cases an explanation what the code does should always be in a good answer! Not only for the OP, but also for future SO visitors!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are two things that make me *very* happy about this question. The first is, someone gave you code that apparently works, *and* you want to understand it more. That's a very good sign that you'll learn a lot from the site.

The second is, *And he already did so much so I didn't ask him for an explanation.* - you're also *considerate*, which is also a good sign that you'll do well on the site. But, don't be *too* shy to ask people to explain something about their answer, *most* on the site would just be delighted that you really want to learn.

You can post the code and ask for clarification, but you need to do the following:

1. Link to the answer you received (e.g. Someone provided this answer to my question about (something), it works, but I don't understand *why* it works.
2. Talk through the code to the point that you understand it. E.g. "I understand everything up to the line where it says 'unicorns'"
3. Tell folks exactly what you don't understand. Is it an operand or an operation (e.g bitwise op)
4. You can even go on to ask if there's a perhaps slightly less efficient, but simpler to comprehend way to accomplish the same thing

Just make it clear that you got code, it works, and you'd be delighted to know *why* it works. We don't see ... as many with natural curiosity ... as we'd like to these days.

If you run into trouble point to this meta post. English is obviously a bit of a challenge for you still, but I think you'll do fine if you spend a bit of time composing the question.

Comment: Thank you. I'll ask in the comments for 'why it works', clearly and precisely per line.

Comment: @HydraCles As an addendum to this, you may consider putting a comment on the original answer with a link to your "explanation" question. The OP will likely be more than happy to post an answer!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET That's actually a rather creative way of getting useful stuff on the site while saying thanks 'twice'. I wouldn't do it except in exemplary cases, but really a neat idea :)

Comment: @TimPost Obviously Thanks, Obviously I would recommend just asking for the clarification in the comments first :) But if the OP is going to the trouble of making a new question, I as an answerer would certainly like seeing such a message!

Answer (score 7):

If you do not understand how the answer 'works', you can ask for clarification in the comments - it's what they're *for*. However, you must ensure your question is **as specific as possible** in order for the answers to be **as useful as possible**. That way, they can add details on your specific question. I cannot speak on behalf of the answerer, but it seems that they have 'solved' the issue, however, your question seems to be posted in such a way that more than a few 'explanation lines' would be required.

In future, just ensure your question can be answered and explained in such a way that the answerer can see the exact issue and be able to explain the issue to you.

If they have done something to help you, then I'm sure they would be quite happy for a reputation 'upvote' to say thanks. Even more, once you accept and answer, they'll get even more! So asking for a short explanation would be in no doubt that said answerer would be happy to explain and share they're knowledge if they have taken the time to answer your question in the first place :).

Comment: So I'll add a good valued question in the comments. Not a new question. But isn't it rude / mean to remove the 'accepted' thing from someone and move it to someone else? I already accepted it...

Comment: @HydraCles: If it is asking for clarification from the answerer, and not a 'whole new question', then I would say leave a comment, since it is still addressing the original issue. If, however, It is a **different issue**, then create a new question, possibly linking to your previous question.

Comment: That helps, and because it still belongs to the original question I'll add it in the comments.