# Is it on-topic to ask about popular framework's code you don't understand?

Tags: support, scope

Often my questions arise when I am trying to understand popular frameworks. Clearly, these are not the same type of questions than those that arise when we write code perhaps while using these framework. These type of questions seem less popular. Are they nevertheless on topic?

It's not exactly the same question  as [Is asking for an explanation of some code on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292026/is-asking-for-an-explanation-of-some-code-on-topic). This other question is whether it is OK to follow-up a question by another one that asks explanation about some code snippet that was provided in the answer to the previous question.  But, they are very much related and the accepted answer to this other question gives the general idea that asking questions about existing code is fine. I am OK, if we consider it as a duplicate.

Comment: This is very...... broad as a "style" of questions. Could you give, maybe, a slightly more specific example? That would help narrow down what exactly you want to ask

Comment: I have asked questions like that. I assume you can lookup. For these specific questions, people that answered were happy to help. It worked fine. Here, I want to know if other people ask similar questions (about popular framework), because I do not want to do different from every one else. That's the purpose of the question.

Comment: Not sure whether I'm understanding what you're asking but... A question that basically says "Explain this to me, I don't understand" tends to be "broad". It would be important to phrase it very narrowly, possibly with a bit of code to illustrate the "pain point".

Comment: Yes, of course, the questions should be made very specific by referring to specific bits of code. On that respect, it's the same as questions that arise when you write code. The only difference, but it is an important difference, is that the questions arise when you try to read and understand code, not when you write code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe double-beep’s dupe is more relevant and a better dupe

Comment: I accept that it is a duplicate of "I don't understand this code ... " . It obviously is. Well, it means that these questions are not welcome in SO, because that was the accepted answer in the duplicate. Strangely, the upvoted answer below says the opposite. However, this answer is in my view inappropriate. You cannot accept these questions and at the same time warn the person asking that very often your question will be considered non interesting and down voted. You either accept these questions kindly or you don't accept them.

Answer (score 5):

It can be fine and on-topic. The devil is in the details, though.

It would depend on the specifics of the question, how is it framed, how much explaining the asker needs, how self-contained is the question, etc.

And many times it would end up being a duplicate anyway, since whatever one does not understand about some code is likely to be a more general principle/technique/pattern that has been already asked sometime before.

There is nothing inherently wrong in asking dupes, sometimes a dupe-link is all that is needed to help the asker and future readers.

I'm going to use two of your latest questions as examples for how this can play out specifically:

- [What's the role of the random string after ComposerAutoloaderInit in autoload.php?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57540826/1426539)

This question is fine. If an asker is not familiar with some of the places composer's autoloader might end up being used, this specific technique may look  confusing. For many users the answer might be obvious after a bit of thought, but that's fine; not everybody is the same.

The answer this question got is short, descriptive and useful.

<sub>(As an aside, I would remove the first paragraph. It's completely besides the point. Sometimes your motivation can be relevant in a question, since they illuminate the direction an answerer might take to answer. In this case, it is just trivia; can be distracting and make the question look worse than actually is).</sub>

- [Why storing $loader as a class property of ComposerAutoloaderInitXXXX in autoload_real.php in composer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57598716/1426539)

This is an example of one of the cases I mentioned earlier. This question can be answered very effectively by pointing users to general explanations about "What a Singleton is" and "How to implement the Singleton pattern in PHP". Once you are aware of that, it's obvious. This is just an example of that pattern and its application.

I do have some problems with this question. You seem to be already aware this is an example of the singleton pattern. You even tagged the question [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleton). So it's not immediately clear exactly what are you asking here.

Is this a yes/no question? It just wants to *confirm* if this is a singleton or not? This doesn't make for a very interesting question, and as it is it's much too long and winded to simply ask that. Which you seem to have already gathered anyway.

Does the question ask why is the safeguard against multiple instantiation necessary? It seems like a strange question to me. Why do we use safe-guards and sanity-checks when programming? Because we are not in control of the *client* application that will use our code, nor the environment where our application. Again, this is not (IMO) a very interesting question, nor it is specific to the code you are trying to understand.

As it is, I believe the question is a dupe at best, and not a particularly good one.

<sub>(Another aside: again, you start with a paragraph that doesn't do any favours to your question: a link to question that's not relevant, general context that is not important to answer your question, a mention that you want to "extract principles, best-practices" which will predispose many users to think of your question as too-broad or opinion based although it is neither. Try put less commentary in your questions and focus on the specifics).</sub>

---

As you can see, there is no blanket "I need help to understand this code" rule. It will depend entirely about the question. It's like "are questions about debugging code OK?". Many times they are, many times they are not.

Comment: This answer shows there is a misunderstanding. The singleton tag was only added after I received the answer in the comments. I could absolutely not have added the tag before. I knew about singleton, but obviously I did not make the link before I received the comment. I feel weird that we say it is a duplicate, because  I (and many others that try to understand the same framework) would not ask the question in terms of singleton.  I humbly admit that it shows that the notion of singleton was not lively in my mind and I feel it's not nice to say that my question was not good because of that.

Comment: Even if you didn't know it was a singleton, it is. There is nothing wrong in now knowing something. But the dupe applies, IMO. _"Why does this is being done this way?"_. _"It's an application of the singleton pattern"_. I don't believe the question is bad because it is a dupe, but because it's not very clear. Maybe it should be edited for clarity (and not to add [meta-commentary](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57598716/revisions)). But even if clear, it's most likely a dupe. (Or a very uninteresting question: "why do we use this safeguard for singletons?").

Comment: Just used those two questions to illustrate that some of these questions are going to be better than others. Use the feedback as you will. Good luck!

Comment: To be more precise, I did consider the possibility that the purpose of the bit of code was to avoid a duplicate, but I did not make the link with the general notion of singleton. Again, it shows that this general notion was not lively in my mind  when I asked the question and I feel weird that we say that the question is not good because of that. Again, many others might be in the same situation while trying to understand this general framework.

Comment: It kinda seems like you are not reading what I'm writing. I'm afraid I wont be able to help you here. I'm sorry! Bye.

Comment: What you suggest is that we should edit questions sincerely asked because we don't know so that they become more obvious and almost pointless.

Comment: Again, you assume too much. I don't know why but the application I am using is not showing edition conflicts. So I actually wrote my comments without being aware of your preceding comments.

Comment: Just so that we are clear, your answer cannot help anyone that don't have the knowledge before asking the question to know in advance that the question will be considered pointless, not interesting and perhaps down voted, etc. So your answer is basically saying that it's fine to ask this type of questions but be warned that your question might be considered non interesting and downvoted and there is nothing you can do about this, except not ask the question in SO and try to find the answer elsewhere.